# How to exchange a credential whilst ensuring deniable authentification?

Tags: public-key

This is a follow-up to this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/96283/88017). The context & vocabulary used is that of a decentralized identity system.

Let $I$ be the issuer of a credential, $H$ the holder and $V$ the verifier.
In this setting, $I$ signs a credential $C$ with their private key, and hands it over to $H$ for storage, who may then present it to $V$ to prove their identity.

One flaw remains in this system: if such were the intentions of  $V$, nothing prevents them from giving the signed data contained in $C$ to a third-party, who could then verify & attest that the credential is authentic even though $H$ didn't give the credential themself.

How could this be avoided?

---

*Note: regarding the link between this question and the answer cited above, I'm not sure if the question I asked about deniable authentication was formulated well enough: I wasn't interested in making the ZKP unreadable to third parties (I fear this is impossible if Bob / $V$ is part of the conspiracy), but my goal was to make the whole credential (*passport*, in that case) no longer provably authentic.*

Answer (score 2):

The solution is rather simple; instead of letting $H$ give the general credential $C$ to $V$, the following steps could be taken:

1. $H$ sends $C$ to $I$, along with $V$'s public key.
2. $I$ checks that they signed the credential themself, takes the content, and signs it again with a *ring signature* made from $V$'s public key and $I$'s own private key. The resulting credential may be called $C_V$. It is sent back to $H$.
3. $H$ sends $C_V$ to $V$ as a proof of identity.

At this point, $V$ can trust the received credential, as the potential signers are $\{I, V\}$, and $V$ knows they didn't sign it.
When $V$ tries to leak the data, they have no way of proving the data authentic.

Comment: The main disadvantage of this solution is that it requires $I$ to sign $C$ with a separate ring signature for each verifier $V$. In practice (if there are too many potential verifiers $V$ for $I$ to issue ring signatures for all of them in advance) that might require real-time communication between $H$ and $I$ (or at least between $H$ and some additional party entrusted by $I$ to perform step 2 on their behalf). But, as I noted in my comment on the original discussion, I'm not actually sure this *can* be done in general without such extra communication.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Yes, that's problematic. I wish there has a way to "ring-sign" something only with (a) the non-signers' PKs and (b) the already-signed message with the SK. I might ask a question about that, at first sight it doesn't seem unfeasible and that would be a hell  of an elegant solution. (edit: Or maybe it *is* unfeasible, but I don't know enough about the math behind signing to tell)

Comment: It's done: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/97819/88017. I'm not really expecting any miracle, though.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Looks like it's impossible without communication, you were right.

Comment: Btw there is the partial solution of the issuer signing using sub-keys, which are rotated out after a period of time. The private keys for the rotated-out sub-keys are released so that anyone could forge the existence of a credential prior to that expiry. However, if the verifier records proof of knowledge of the credentials e.g. on a blockchain prior to the keys being rotated out, then this mechanism fails. See https://www.mit.edu/~specter/blog/2020/dkim/

Answer (score 0):

Use a zero knowledge proof that the signature exists rather than sending a signature directly.

The holder and verifier execute the protocol and this convinces the verifier that the signature exists without revealing it.

[For signatures based on discrete log problems (Schnorr signatures, ED25519, ECDSA) this transformation is easy to do. If the Verifier has a known public key, the Holder can do this in a single message.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42648/19869)

Other signature algorithms also allow existence ZKPs but may require arithmetic circuit proofs.