# NIZK Proof of Knowledge of a Standard RSA Signature on a message (without signer participation)

Tags: rsa, signature, zero-knowledge-proofs

I'm looking for a protocol in which a Prover transforms a RSA signature $\sigma$ on a message $m$ that verifies under a public key $vk$ into a NIZK proof of knowledge, $\pi$ of that signature. A verifier should then be able to verify that the prover saw a signature for that message and that the signature would have verified under the public key, $vk$.

The protocol has three parties: a signer, a prover and a verifier. The signer is the only party that knows the signing key $sk=d$. The signer is not aware the protocol is being run and just sends signatures to the prover.

We assume the public key $vk$, message $m$, and $\pi$ are all public, the original signature $\sigma$ is known to the prover, but is kept secret from the verifier. The verifier should not be able to learn the signature $\sigma$.

The purpose of this protocol is to create a public transparency log of signatures and messages that can be audited without leaking the actual signatures and presenting the risk of an attacker replaying these signatures. Unlike this

Below I provide my draft of such a protocol:

RSA Public key: $vk=(e, n)$; RSA Signing key: $sk=(d)$; Hash function: $y \gets h(x)$

**Signer** receives message $m$ and computes the RSA signature:
$\sigma \gets h(m)^d \mod n$ and then transmits $(\sigma,m)$ to the Prover.

**Prover** on receiving $(\sigma,m)$ computes $\pi$ via the following steps:

$$r \xleftarrow{\\\$} \mathbb{Z}_n^* \phantom{\mod n}$$
$$w \gets r^{e} \mod n$$
$$\pi \gets \sigma r \mod n \equiv h(m)^d r \mod n$$

and publishes $(\pi, w, m)$

**Verifier** on learning $(\pi, w, m)$ verifies these values under the verification key of the signer, $e$.

If computed honestly by the prover $\pi^e$ should be: $\pi^e \mod n \equiv
(h(m)^d r)^e \mod n \equiv (h(m) r^e) \mod n \equiv h(m) w \mod n$$

...so to verify the verifier checks that
$$ \pi^e  \mod n \stackrel{?}{=} h(m) w \mod n$$

Since $r$ is randomly chosen it functions like a blinding factor hiding $\sigma$ from the Verifier. An adversary A that can recover $\sigma$ from $(\pi, w)$ can be used to invert the function RSA on $w$ by choosing $\pi$ randomly, getting $\sigma$ and the dividing $\sigma$ from $\pi$ to learn $w^d$.

**Edit:** As pointed out by https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/452/poncho in their answer, my draft protocol is very insecure. Do not use.

**Questions:**

- Is the above scheme actually secure i.e., can the Prover construct a $\pi$ which the Verifier will accept without having seen the signature and can the Verifier recover $\sigma$ from $\pi$?
- If it is secure what is the name of the paper from the 1990s that
  first did it?
- What other approaches are there?

Unlike [Proving the possession of signature in zero-knowledge](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16015/proving-the-possession-of-signature-in-zero-knowledge) we aren't interested in privacy. It is perfectly fine if $\pi$ can be linked to a particular $\sigma$ by a party that already knows $\sigma$.

This problem seems very similar to [GQ signatures](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/88314.88372) but GQ signatures assume the prover is generating the message and binding it to their identity where their identity is also a signature.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the above scheme actually secure i.e., can the Prover construct a $\pi$
> which the Verifier will accept without having seen the signature and can the Verifier recover $\sigma$
> from $\pi$?

No, the scheme is not secure, in the sense that the Prover can construct a $\pi, w$ pair that validates.

All the Prover needs to do is select an arbitrary $\pi$ and compute $w = \pi^e \cdot h(m)^{-1}$.

Comment: Good eyes! You are correct, it is not secure. So this is why GQ signatures commit to the $T$ first and later have the challenge value $d$ sent over?

The more I think about it, the more I probably just want GQ signatures